# Add sample size to ggplot2 bar plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to produce bar graph with ggplot2 in R.
Graph is produced perfectly so far but when I try adding sample size, it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(dplyr)
library(ggsignif)
Demo1 <- demo.csv("demo.csv", header = T, sep = ",")
Demo1
mean <- aggregate(A ~ B, Demo1, mean)
sd <- aggregate(A ~ B, Demo1, sd)
samplesize <- Demo1 %>% group_by(B) %>% summarise(count = n())

X <- ggplot(Demo1, aes(y = B, x = A))
X <- X + stat_summary(fun = "mean", 
                  geom = "bar") 
X <- X + stat_summary(fun = "mean", 
                  geom = "errorbar",
                  fun.min = function(x)mean(x)-sd(x), 
                  fun.max = function(x)mean(x) + sd(x), 
                  width = 0.1,
                  size = 0.5)
X <- X + theme_classic()
```

Then, tried to paste samplesize which I calculated in the beginning by following code.

```
X <- X + geom_text(aes(x = A, y = B, label = samplesize))
```

Is there any good way to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for your advice. I added little more code.

Comment: @user3121518 Thanks for your advice. I added little more code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>%
  count(cyl) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(cyl, n, label = n) + 
  geom_col() + geom_text(vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]

---

For your data you can try to add -

```
X + geom_text(data = samplesize, aes(label = count), vjust = -5.5, hjust = -0.5)
```

Adjust `hjust` and `vjust` value according to your choice.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response! This code worked but how can I add sample size text to the bar graph I produced by the code I shared? Thanks

Comment: The code is not useful for us because we don't have data (`Demo1`) to run it. Please edit your post to include output of `dput(Demo1)` or if the data is huge use `dput(head(Demo1, 20))`

Comment: Thanks. I tried to edit my post but eventhough I use proper formatting, error message about code formatting appears and cannot post anymore. Here is the data I used
`> dput(read.table(pipe("pbpaste")))
structure(list(V1 = c("A", "21days", "21days", "21days", "21days", 
"3days", "3days", "3days", "3days"), V2 = c("B", "50", "100", 
"150", "200", "30", "60", "90", "120")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))`

Comment: @Ritz Can you try `X + geom_text(data = samplesize, aes(label = count), vjust = -5.5, hjust = -0.5)`. I have also updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much again.  I tried and this error came out. "Error in FUN(X[[i]], …) : object 'carrot' not found"
I googled and tried some solutions but nothing worked.

Comment: It worked!! I added x and y as following `X <- X + geom_text(data=samplesize, aes(x=days, y=count, label=count),vjust=0)`
Thank you soo much for your help! This is exactly what I wanted.